# Модульное написание интерфейса Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, tkinter, python-3.6

Возможно мой вопрос покажется странным, не судите строго, с Python и програмированием в целом я столкнулся пару месяцев назад.

Есть графический интерфейс написанный в Tkinter, в интерфейсе есть виджет Notebook с вкладками A, B и C. Появилось огромное желание описывать интерфейс каждой вкладки в отдельном файле: a.py, b.py и т.д.

Поскажите как это правильно реализовать и что посоветуете почитать на эту тему:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MainInterface:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title(version)
        self.window.geometry("1024x768")
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.window['padx'] = 10
        self.window['pady'] = 10

        main_notebook_controll = ttk.Notebook(self.window, width=1000, height=700)

        a_tab = ttk.Frame(main_notebook_controll)
        b_tab = ttk.Frame(main_notebook_controll)
        c_tab = ttk.Frame(main_notebook_controll)

        main_notebook_controll.add(a_tab, text="Notebook A")
        main_notebook_controll.add(b_tab, text="Notebook B")
        main_notebook_controll.add(c_tab, text="Notebook C")

        main_notebook_controll.grid(row=1, column=1)

program = MainInterface()
program.window.mainloop()
```

Comment: создаете файл `a.py`. Добавляете в нем создаете класс (пусть будет TabA), который наследует `ttk.Frame`, этому классу добавляете его виджеты. после в файле с `MainInterface` пишите `from a import TabA` и вместо `a_tab = TabA`. Остальные вкладки так же

Comment: А можно Вас попросить написать пример для одной вкладки А, у меня пока крайне смутное представление о классах, как раз на примере поможет разобраться. А то примеры столами и табуретками на которых разбираюся классы как-то слегка оторваны от реальности.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Результат](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/03e002ec8cb23a656f77e20c2d021e329442b6e6/tkinter_examples/tab_Notebook__with_widgets_as_modules):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

По шагам.

1. Создаем основу приложения

   **main.py**:

   ```
   from tkinter import Tk, ttk
   import tkinter as tk

   class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
       def __init__(self, parent):
           super().__init__(parent)

           self.parent = parent
           self.parent.title('version')

           self.init_ui()

       def init_ui(self):
           self.parent['padx'] = 10
           self.parent['pady'] = 10

           self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self, width=1000, height=700)

           a_tab = tk.Frame(self.notebook)
           b_tab = tk.Frame(self.notebook)
           c_tab = tk.Frame(self.notebook)

           self.notebook.add(a_tab, text="Notebook A")
           self.notebook.add(b_tab, text="Notebook B")
           self.notebook.add(c_tab, text="Notebook C")

           self.notebook.pack()

           self.pack()
   ```
2. Создаем виджеты

   **tab_a.py**:

   ```
   import tkinter as tk    

   class Example(tk.Frame):
       def __init__(self, parent):
           super().__init__(parent)

           self.parent = parent
           self.init_ui()

       def init_ui(self):
           self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

           acts = ['Scarlett Johansson', 'Rachel Weiss', 'Natalie Portman', 'Jessica Alba']

           self.lb = tk.Listbox(self)
           for i in acts:
               self.lb.insert(tk.END, i)
               self.lb.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.on_select)
               self.lb.pack(pady=15)

           self.var = tk.StringVar()
           self.label = tk.Label(self, text=0, textvariable=self.var)
           self.label.pack()

           self.pack()

       def on_select(self, val):
           sender = val.widget
           idx = sender.curselection()
           value = sender.get(idx)

           self.var.set(value)
   ```

   **tab_b.py**:

   ```
   import tkinter as tk

   class Example(tk.Frame):
       def __init__(self, parent):
           super().__init__(parent)

           self.parent = parent
           self.init_ui()

       def init_ui(self):
           self.text = tk.Text(self, width=20, height=10)
           self.text.pack()
           self.text.insert(1.0, 'Hello World!\nFoo\nBar\n\n123\n')

           self.button = tk.Button(self, text='Append', command=self.on_append)
           self.button.pack()

           self.pack()

       def on_append(self):
           self.text.insert(tk.END, 'Go-go-go!\n')
   ```

   **tab_c.py**:

   ```
   import tkinter as tk

   class Example(tk.Frame):
       def __init__(self, parent):
           super().__init__(parent)

           self.parent = parent
           self.init_ui()

       def init_ui(self):
           self.button = tk.Button(self, text='Append', command=self.on_click)
           self.button.pack()

           self.pack()

       def on_click(self):
           print('Hello World!')
   ```
3. Добавляем в `main.py` импорт виджетов и добавляем их на вкладки

   **main.py**:

   ```
   from tkinter import Tk, ttk
   import tkinter as tk

   from tab_a import Example as TabA
   from tab_b import Example as TabB
   from tab_c import Example as TabC


   class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
       def __init__(self, parent):
           super().__init__(parent)

           self.parent = parent
           self.parent.title('version')

           self.init_ui()

       def init_ui(self):
           self.parent['padx'] = 10
           self.parent['pady'] = 10

           self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self, width=1000, height=700)

           a_tab = TabA(self.notebook)
           b_tab = TabB(self.notebook)
           c_tab = TabC(self.notebook)

           self.notebook.add(a_tab, text="Notebook A")
           self.notebook.add(b_tab, text="Notebook B")
           self.notebook.add(c_tab, text="Notebook C")

           self.notebook.pack()

           self.pack()


   if __name__ == '__main__':
       root = Tk()
       root.title('version')
       ex = MainWindow(root)
       root.geometry("300x250")
       root.mainloop()
   ```

---

**PS.**

**main.py** с структурой из вопроса:

```
from tkinter import Tk, ttk
import tkinter as tk

from tab_a import Example as TabA
from tab_b import Example as TabB
from tab_c import Example as TabC


class MainInterface:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title('version')
        self.window.geometry("1024x768")
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.window['padx'] = 10
        self.window['pady'] = 10

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.window, width=1000, height=700)

        a_tab = TabA(self.notebook)
        b_tab = TabB(self.notebook)
        c_tab = TabC(self.notebook)

        self.notebook.add(a_tab, text="Notebook A")
        self.notebook.add(b_tab, text="Notebook B")
        self.notebook.add(c_tab, text="Notebook C")

        self.notebook.grid(row=1, column=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    program = MainInterface()
    program.window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ, так намного понятнее!