# Как вставить текст в находящийся в текущей вкладке виджет Text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Недавно узнал о виджете Notebook . И захотел сделать динамическое добавление вкладок .

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
n = ttk.Notebook(root)
n.pack(fill = X)
tab = 1

def new_tab():
    global tab
    text = Text(root)
    text.pack()
    n.add(text, text = ("tab "+str(tab)))
    tab += 1

def check():
   '''код для вставки текста в виджет Text'''
   ...
   
    

plus = Button(root,text = '+', command=new_tab)
plus.pack(side = LEFT)

check_button = Button(root, text = 'check', command = check)
check_button.pack(side = LEFT)


root.mainloop()
```

Добавление вкладок я сделал, но при попытке вставить какой либо текст с помощью insert в функции check, python выдаёт ошибку. Но проблема не совсем в ошибке. Я хотел вставить текст в текстовый виджет находящийся в текущей вкладке.

Comment: Текст для примера- "Hello , tab"

Comment: Здесь есть insert в Notebook для Tkinter: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/919894

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Индекс выбранной вкладки можно получить так: `n.index(n.select())`
2. Добавляете каждое новое созданное текстовое поле в список
3. В функции `check` определяете индекс выбранной вкладки (см. п. 1), по этому индексу из списка текстовых полей получаете текстовое поле текущей вкладки, в это текстовое поле добавляете текст

Пример:

```
text_widgets = []


def new_tab():
    text = Text(root)
    text.pack()
    text_widgets.append(text)
    n.add(text, text=f"tab {len(text_widgets)}")


def check():
    current_tab_index = n.index(n.select())
    text_widgets[current_tab_index].insert(END, "Some text\n")
```

Другой вариант: `n.select()` возвращает текстовый `id` виджета в текущей вкладке (в вашем случае это будет `id` текстового поля), получить сам виджет можно с помощью метода `root.nametowidget()`:

```
tab = 1


def new_tab():
    global tab
    text = Text(root)
    text.pack()
    n.add(text, text=f"tab {tab}")
    tab += 1


def check():
    widget_id = n.select()
    root.nametowidget(widget_id).insert(END, "Some text\n")
```